# Resolution for conflicting 'Provides' in RPM spec

Tags: conflict, rpm, yum, rpm-spec, package-management

Consider a situation where there are different rpms that provide the same capability. A hypothetical example would be let Oracle JDK rpm, Oracle JRE rpm,and OpenJDK rpm all have "java-env" listed in the "Provides" field in their SPEC files. Now we have rpms like ant, groovy, maven all having the "Requires" field set to "java-env" in their SPEC files. What gets installed when an attempt is made to install groovy or maven? In what ways can we control what dependency gets installed? I think one way would be to put Oracle JDK rpm, Oracle JRE rpm,and OpenJDK all in different repositories and set priorities on the repositories, but in this way the number of repos may continue to grow as I have several of these kinds of conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

If multiple packages provide the same functionality, then each of them can be installed. This is mainly a user selection. When the packages are done properly, then it should be possible to install each of them (only one at a time).

The package requiring the environment does not even notice which one is installed or used.

Which package is installed without user-interaction depends on the package manager. Some ask the user, some choose a preferred one, ...

If you NEED a special Java version, then instead of requiring the generic package, you should require that specific package. Problem here is that another package may require another one and then you have an unsolvable conflict. So best is always to use generic `Requires`.

For most systems it is also possible to install multiple java packages. The installation process then chooses the best one as default (via `/etc/alternatives` mechanisms).

Comment: Thanks a lot Dirk!. Off the top of your head do you know what to would be behavior when anaconda (the redhat installer) is resolving dependencies and installing them at OS install time. In the kickstart file there is no mention of jdk/jre but just groovy.

Comment: No, I usually use openSUSE.